# How to run spark project on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache-spark

I am a new user of spark.

I have a spark project that i need to run on eclipse:
I have included all of **the spark jars** and installed **scala plugin**.

when i run the project *as a java project* i get this error:

```
Error: Main method is not static in class scala.tools.nsc.ScalaDoc$, please define the main method as:
public static void main(String[] args)
```

what should i fix ?

**Note**: i am note using maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the project was given to me by my boss.

i was running the hole project **as a javaproject** , when i run only the file that contains *static void main* the execution succeed

Answer (score 0):

As you have installed Scala plugin, create a Scala project. Then create an Scala object with the main method as below

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit ={

}
```